# Linux processes with no usage

Tags: c, process, cpu-usage, raspbian

I made a complex C program that, during its execution, forks many other processes this way:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t childpid = fork();

    if(childpid == -1) {
        perror("Failed to fork");
    }

    if(childpid == 0) {
        setsid();
    int execReturn = execl("/bin/my_code", (char *) 0);
    } else {}

    return 0;
}
```

The point is that when I launch a TOP command from the shell, I can see lots of processes named "my_code", and they all look like this:

```
2377 root      20   0     0    0    0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.14 my_code
2379 root      20   0     0    0    0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.02 my_code
2380 root      20   0     0    0    0 Z   0,0  0,0   0:00.02 my_code
```

I fear this could be dangerous since my code is designed to run continuously without interruption.

Internet didn't help me much.

Note: My OS is Raspbian.

edit:

what I am asking, besides the code, is wether those processes that I see in the TOP output could be dangerous to the CPU or not.

As I said, my code is designed to run continuously, so I don't know if the problem will show up in a week or so.

edit:

I edited my code to make it independent from child processes using system(...) call.

Many thanks to @alk.

Comment: what are you asking us for?

Comment: That code won't compile. Please [edit to show what you mean](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23739013/edit).

Comment: The processes won't hurt the CPU.

Comment: I would more be worried about the "Z"-state.

Comment: @alk I know. I made so that the parent process terminates and then restarts every hundred processes, so I am not worried about zombies that deplete my processes table. I was worried about the time they actually stayed "active".

Comment: If the code runs continously for a long time and with this continues creating zombies, the system is likley to run out of available pids at a certain point in time in the future, as each zombie process require one, and the total number of pids is limited.

Comment: @alk You're right. I edited my code after a little search. (edit in the question)